# libGdx gameView doesn't display in a ScrollView

Tags: android, view, libgdx, scrollview

I am experimenting with ScrollView to be able to scroll up the screen when the soft keyboard appears.
For that I started with a very simple program. In the AndroidLauncher.java, I created a ScrollView and a gameView. I added the gameView to the ScrollView and finished with "setContentView(scrollView)"

Well... I have no errors, the program launches, and display on the screen, but the program doesn't display the gameView. All I see is the background color of the ScrollView.

I put 2 System.out.println("Test") in my code, one at the end of the AndroidLauncher.java, and one in the MyGdxGame.java. Only the test in the AndroidLauncher.java prints, which means that the gameView is not created. Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Here is the code :

AndroidLauncher.java :

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    ScrollView.LayoutParams fParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(fParams);
    scrollView.setBackgroundColor(0xffa3b8fe);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);

    scrollView.addView(gameView);
    setContentView(scrollView);

    System.out.println("Test 1");
}
```

MyGdxGame.java :

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {
SpriteBatch batch;
AssetManager assets;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    assets = new AssetManager();

    System.out.println("Test 2");

    this.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();
}

public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.scroll.test.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.scroll.test.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the (very easy) solution to my problem :
After creating my ScrollView, in the AndroidLauncher.java, I only had to add this method :

```
 scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```

And that works ! My android app displays the gameView.
But now I face another problem. I wanted to put this ScrollView because I wanted the screen to move up when the soft keyboard appears over au textfield.
Although I put this line in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

that doesn't work. The screen doesn't move, and the soft keyboard hides the textField I am using.

Well... that's another matter, and that'll be another question if I don't find the solution.